# Dropdown arrow appears when it shouldn't

Tags: html, css, dropdownbox

I have a problem with IE & firefox. I believe the effect I wanted to achieve works only on chrome.
The problem is that it displays the dropdown perfectly in chrome like on this picture below: [image: correct dropdown]

and in firefox / ie it displays it in this way:
[image]

So, basically it keeps the default dropdown arrow.

here is a code:

```
      <select name="gender">
       <option value="">Gender</option>
       <option value="male">Male</option>
       <option value="female">Female</option>
      </select>
```

and css:

```
input {
height: 67px;
width: 400px;
border:none;
background:url(../_images/butt-reg.png) no-repeat;
padding: 0 20px;
margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
text-align:left;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 18pt;
color: #666;
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution to sort it out, but i tried couple of things and nothing was working.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Style a Select Box Using Only CSS](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)

Comment: Thank you, this is actually a clever solution, however it mainly keeps I would call it a "title part" narrower than the actual dropdown options. Thank you anyway, I may use it in future. Good find.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://result.dabblet.com/gist/3358882/5eeb2b8d4fe6adf243c5c463111d367c7651a029

I have tried to overlay the dropdown button with a custom one by using the after-pseudo-element on the parent node (a label-element in this case). The CSS property pointer-events makes sure that you can still click on the pink button to open the select-control.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this *cross-browser* using **CSS** only is real hard (if not impossible) to do. The only way I can think of to style your `<select>` element is to simulate it. First, insert a hidden text `input` that'll have the selected value. Here's an example HTML that simulates a dropdown-`select` element:

```
<div class = "select">
    <div class = "curVal">Gender</div><div class = "arrow">V</div>
    <div class = "choices">
        <div class = "choice">Male</div>
        <div class = "choice">Female</div>
        <div class = "choice">Refuse to answer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's style it:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;        
}
.select div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.curVal {
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: rgb(0, 162, 232);
    color: white;
}
.arrow {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(0, 140, 200); /* this can be an image */
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
.choices {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 127, 39);
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    width: 150px;
}
.choices div {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;        
}
```

Some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready()(function(){
    $(".choices").hide();
});
$(".arrow").click(function(event) {
   $(".choices").slideToggle("fast");
   event.stopPropagation();
});
$(".choice").click(function() {
   $(".curVal").html($(this).html());
   $(".choices").slideToggle("fast");
   event.stopPropagation();
});
$("html").click(function() {
   $(".choices").slideUp("fast");
});
```

Put them all together, you get this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEtCG/22/).

I hope that helped you in any manner!